# Refresh ListView (with BaseAdapter) after SQLiteDatabase data changed

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

Firstly, I want to apologize for asking this question, because I know that there are a lot similar ones here, but none of the answers solve my problem.

As the title of the question suggests I need to populate ListView with new items when data in SQLiteDatabase changes.

To be more specific...

I have an activity that shows contacts in a **ListView**. At the bottom of the screen I have a button that adds a contact (A **Dialog** pops up with fields for name, phone number etc...).

When an item in the list is clicked another **Dialog** is opened. In that dialog there are 3 buttons for SendSMS (to the selected contact), Edit and Delete contact.

When I fill in the form for adding new contact, or click the Delete button, I want the ListView to refresh.

It doesn't happen. In order to see the updated list I need to navigate back, and start the Contacts activity again.

Here is the code:

**Activity:**

```
public class ContactsActivity extends Activity {


private MyUtilities myUtilities;
private MyDatabaseHelper mdbh;
private AdapterContactListView contactsAdapter;
private ListView contactsListView;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    mdbh = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
    myUtilities = new MyUtilities(this);    
    contactsAdapter = new AdapterContactListView(this,mdbh);
    contactsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactActivityLV);
    contactsListView.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);

    contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    contactsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView phoneNumberTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactElementNumberTV);              
            String phoneNumber = phoneNumberTV.getText().toString();
            Contact contact = mdbh.getContactFromPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);              
            Dialog d = myUtilities.createSelectedContactOptionsDialog(contact);
            d.show();
            contactsAdapter.updateAdapter(mdbh.getAllContacts());               
        }
    });


public void addContact(View view) {
        Dialog d = myUtilities.createAddContactDialog();
        d.show();
        contactsAdapter.updateAdapter(mdbh.getAllContacts());
    }
}
```

**The Adater:**

```
private List<Contact> allContacts;
private int numberOfContacts;
private MyDatabaseHelper mdbh;
private Context context;

public AdapterContactListView(Context c, MyDatabaseHelper m) {
    super();
    context = c;
    mdbh = m;
    allContacts = mdbh.getAllContacts();
    numberOfContacts = allContacts.size();
}

public void updateAdapter(List<Contact> cs) {
    allContacts = cs;
    numberOfContacts = allContacts.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.contact_element, null);
    }
    String fullName = allContacts.get(position).getFirstName();
    fullName = fullName.concat(" ");
    fullName = fullName.concat(allContacts.get(position).getLastName());

    TextView contactName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactElementNameTV);
    TextView phoneNumber = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactElementNumberTV);

    contactName.setText(fullName);
    phoneNumber.setText(allContacts.get(position).getPhoneNumber());

    return view;
}
```

The job of the dialogs is to do operations with the database (update, add, delete).

I tried placing the `notifyDataSetChanged()` right after `updateAdapter()` and in the `updateAdapter()` method itself, but none of that works.

**One thing I think I might be missing:**

The definition `notifyDataSetChanged()` says that it notifies attached observers. I have no attached observers, but in all the answers that I have read no one mentioned anything about attaching an observer. If you think this is the problem, please tell me how to do this.

Can someone, please, shed some light on this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, no, no, dont use BaseAdapter,  use SimpleCursorAdapter instead

Comment: I'm sorry for being ignorant, but everything I have tried fails. My adapter now extends CursorAdapter. The ListView is populated fine, but the problem persists. When I dismiss the dialog the list is not refreshed. I still need to close the activity and start it again in order to see the correct list. I tried calling `adapter.changeCursor` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` after dismissing the dialog (because the dialog handles database operations). I tried calling it in `onResume`... but nothing. Please help! I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh your listview, either you can call a method from a list called notifydatasetchanged but that will only work when youll get the contacts in the contactsalllist. So what you need to do is that you should first get the new data in your arraylist and then call notifydataset changed on your listview.

Apart from that if you are using Contacts database I would recommend you using a simplecursoradapter instead of using the baseadapter but its completely upto you. Anyhow I have added the code for that as well. Let me know if it helps you.

```
    /**
     * 
     * @author Syed Ahmed Hussain
     */
    public class TestListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, MultiChoiceModeListener {

    NotificationsAdapter mNotificationAdapter;

    ListView mNotificationsListView;
    TextView mTxtNotificationsInfo;
    Button mBtnCreateNotification;

    public static final String TAG = "NotificationsList";


    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle pSavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_notifications);
        initializeUIElements();
//      registerForContextMenu(mNotificationsListView);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        mNotificationsListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        mNotificationsListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void initializeUIElements() {
        mTxtNotificationsInfo   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNotificationInfo);
        mNotificationsListView  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_notifications);
        mBtnCreateNotification  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddNotification);
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * 
     */
    public void onCreateNewNotificationClick(View pV) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateNewNotificationClick");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddNewNotification.class);
        startActivity(intent);
//      setResult(0);
//      finish();
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int pId, Bundle pArgs) {
        return new android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), NotificationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> pLoader, Cursor pData) {
        if (pData == null || pData.getCount() == 0) {
            Log.d("pData", "is null");
            showTextView();
            return;
        }
        mNotificationAdapter = new NotificationsAdapter(this, R.layout.item_notification, pData, new String[] { NotificationDatabaseHelper.COL_TITLE }, new int[] {R.id.txtNotificationTitle}, 0);
        mNotificationsListView.setAdapter(mNotificationAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> pLoader) {

    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Hides the list view. shows the textview
     */
    private void showTextView() {
        mNotificationsListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mTxtNotificationsInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Multi-choice list item

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode pMode, Menu pMenu) {
         // Inflate the menu for the CAB
        MenuInflater inflater = pMode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list_item, pMenu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode pMode, Menu pMenu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode pMode, MenuItem pItem) {

        switch (pItem.getItemId()) {
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), pItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pMode.finish();
            break;

        case 2:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), pItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pMode.finish();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode pMode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode pMode, int pPosition, long pId, boolean pChecked) {

    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu_items, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

**

- Notification Adapter is a Simple Curser Adapter:

**

```
/**
 *  
 * @author Syed Ahmed Hussain
 */
public class NotificationsAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {


    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mLayout;

    public NotificationsAdapter(Context pContext, int pLayout, Cursor pC, String[] pFrom, int[] pTo, int pFlags) {
        super(pContext, pLayout, pC, pFrom, pTo, pFlags);
        mLayout             = pLayout;
        mContext            = pContext;
        mLayoutInflater     = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);


    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context pContext, Cursor pCursor, ViewGroup pParent) {
        return mLayoutInflater.inflate(mLayout, null);
    }

}
```

To get it updated whenever you have a change in records do notifydatasetchange or take a refresh cursor to get all the values. Recall the method which returns you the dataset/cursor.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed and pskink. I have not yet solved my problem, but your answers made me dig a little deeper. I found here: [link](http://www.gustekdev.com/2013/05/custom-cursoradapter-and-why-not-use.html) that it is better to use 'CursorAdapter' then 'SimpleCursorAdapter' because of additional control. I'll let you know when I have solved the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @Djole this guy is wrong: SCA is in 99% cases better than CA